# How to create Disk shortcut on desktop using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut

I'm trying to create a shortcut to my disk C on desktop using PowerShell.

```
$TargetFile = "$env:C:\"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:E:\Users\Oskar.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object  -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

The problem is it creates a shortcut but in some random localization on C drive. 

My Desktop is on E drive. How is it possbile that the shortcut is created on C drive if the path is E:\Users\Oskar.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?. 
Thanks in advance, Oskar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$env:VAR` looks for an environment variable named `VAR`.

So your `"$env:E:\Users\Oskar.lnk"` looks for an environment variable named `E:\Users\Oskar.lnk`, which doesn't exist, so it uses an empty string.

This causes your shortcut to be saved to the (Win32 process's) current directory (note: this is not necessarily the same as PowerShell's current directory).

You should use `$ShortcutFile = "E:\Users\Oskar.lnk"`.

Similarly for the other place where you've used `$env:`...